# performance same image in different angles

Tags: android, html, css, optimization

i have arrow image , which i need in different angles top, left ,bottom ,right

i was guessing what could be better 
1: changing image direction via css and loading main image

```
<img src="a.png">
<img src="a.png" style="transform: rotate(90deg);">
<img src="a.png" style="transform: rotate(180deg);">
<img src="a.png" style="transform: rotate(270deg);">
```

2: making new image with that angle and calling that

```
<img src="a.png">
<img src="b.png">
<img src="c.png">
<img src="d.png">
```

or any other way ??

most important i will be using that html in android html app so very minute things count.
whole html will be called from assest folder of andorid

Answer (score 0):

It's generally going to be faster to just use CSS transforms, as long as you are sure all your target browsers support it.

This makes sense, if you think about it: it's faster to do a few calculations on the local CPU than to load 4 separate images, just because network speeds are almost always slower than CPU speeds.

However, you might also consider caching: with 4 separate images, the browser can cache those images so they are no longer loaded from the internet per page load.

Ultimate though, the performance speed, unless we're talking about hundreds of images here or a very slow webserver, is extremely negligible.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use this on browsers that don't support CSS transform then you have no choice and you have to use the second one.

That said you could combine the the four arrows into a single image and then use CSS spite position to pull the correct orientation out of the larger image.

```
<img src="arrow.png" class="direction-up">
<img src="arrow.png" class="direction-right">
<img src="arrow.png" class="direction-down">
<img src="arrow.png" class="direction-left">
```

with the appropriate CSS classes defined and positions calculated according to your image size.

After the image(s) first download and hit the local browser cache there's going to be very little difference, and anything under 40ms is faster than the human eye can actually see change.

typically small images only take a 1-2 ms to download anyway (but with a much much longer request / response overhead for each one) so combining them into a single image sprite actually makes it more efficient.

Downloading a single arrow image Vs downloading a spite with 4 arrows combined will probably take identical times (according to your browsers ability to report it to the nearest .1ms) as most of the time taken will actually be network overhead in dealing with the request.